# Opencv binary mask into white and blue mask

Tags: numpy, opencv

Let's say I have a mask (100, 100) of 1's and 0's:

```
mask = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(100, 100))
```

How to convert this mask to get white-and-blue image in RGB:

- 1's from mask goes blue
- 0's from mask goes white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy as piece of cake. You need auxiliary array to do it:

```
img = np.zeros((100, 100, 3))
img[mask==0,:] = [1, 1, 1] 
img[mask==1,:] = [0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: in the OpenCV case, it's BGR instead of RGB, and the values may need to be 255 (if the array is of dtype uint8), but 1 is good if it's of dtype float32/64.